# How does zero voltage switching work if VDS = 0?

Tags: mosfet, zvs

One of the fundamental criteria to put a MOSFET in to saturation is for its VDS > VGS-VT.

It's also my understanding that zero voltage switching works by first decreasing VDS (ideally to 0) before applying a VGS>VT. This eliminates switching losses by eliminating the Ids overlap with Vds.

My question is, how would any current flow if VDS = 0 in ZVS? The MOSFET equations clearly say that it wouldn't.

[image]

[Image from Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/Vishay_Zero_Voltage_Switching.pdf)

Comment: You need to consider the bigger circuit picture; the flow of current is determined by factors that are external to the MOSFET and, the voltage across the MOSFET is determined by external factors too. All the MOSFET zero-voltage-crossing circuit can do is await for these conditions to be true.

Answer (score 1):

To give you an answer would be saying "shrewd" circuit design will lead you to the desired effect.

there is not a gold standard on how to achieve this, but resonant circuits are good example of one way to obtain 0 voltage(near 0) between drain and source while switching.

Do remember that ideally you consider the voltage zero, but you just want to get it as low as you possibly can to minimize the losses if the topology allows it. Sadly, you have to observe this in a case by case basis and having a circuit example at hand is best.

[image: Example of ZVS]

I suggest you read this article to familiarize yourself better for this example, but in general if you understand the resonant frequency of Cr and Lr you can time your gate signal accordingly to turn on the switch at the most convenient time.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup089/slup089.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I'm less concerned about the mechanism of how to get VDS=0, and more concerned about the fact that intuition says with a VDS=0, the MOSFET would be trioded and no current should flow. this is where I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The FET used as a switch works in two operating modes. To open the switch, you put the transistor to cutoff, to close the switch, you put the transistor to the ohmic mode. Typically you want the closed switch resistance to be held as low as possible, and you apply the maximum gate voltage to close the switch (see the right plot of the image below).

With a power transistor IPD04N03LA, you can design a DC DC converter yielding up to 50A output current. Look at the typical output characteristics:

[image: IPD04N03LA.png]

To provide for a continuous drain current of 50A, the voltage across the transistor in saturation should be greater than 1V (and \$V_{GS}=3.4V\$), whereas in the ohmic mode you can apply a gate voltage of \$V_{GS}=10V\$ and have a \$V_{DS}\$ as small as 76mV. Not zero, but more than an order of magnitude smaller than for the transistor in saturation.

The FETs in saturation mode are used in amplifiers and current sources. This mode is not used for switching operations with low losses.

If you switch a field effect transistor into the conductive state and the voltage across the transistor is greater than the voltage drop across the closed switch (\$I_D·R_{DS}\$, where \$R_{DS}\$ is a drain-source on-state resistance), the transients result in excessive power losses. To eliminate these unnecessary losses, zero voltage switching technique is invented. A modifier "zero" in ZVS should not be taken too literally. You cannot get rid of a voltage drop across the non-ideal closed switch entirely. As for the opening phrase of the question, the FETs in ZVS circuits are never being put intentionally to saturation for switching operations and `VDS > VGS-VT` is not a constraint in ZVS circuit designs.